# what is the compatible protobuf version for latest grpc v1.61.0

Tags: build, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to build grpc latest version, but getting failed due to error as below:

CMake Error at cmake/protobuf.cmake:58 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Protobuf" with any
of the following names:

```
ProtobufConfig.cmake
protobuf-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "Protobuf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Protobuf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"Protobuf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:332 (include)

using grpc version 1.61.0, protobuf 3.24.4
Platform gcc 5.13.0-30-generic